# Running other generator within a generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thor

I created a scaffolding gem that uses another gem to generate presenters. I created this scaffolding generator using the Rails 3 generators. It works like this:

```
rails g stager:scaffold User
```

I created another gem to generate presenters. I want to use this gem to generate a presenter with each scaffold. Currently I'm doing the following to accomplish this:

```
run "rails g exhibit:presenter #{scaffold_name}"
```

The problem is that it seems to reload the Rails environment when this generator is called, making it a bit slow. I'm wondering if there's a better way to call another generator within a generator. So: is there a better way to create a Rails generator inception? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define a `hook_for` the other generator in your generator class. The `ScaffoldGenerator` is probably the best example of this, as it [has a hook for the `scaffold_controller` generator.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb#L12)

If you want to pass in arguments to your generator, it's probably better to use something like the `hook_for` examples further down in this file for assets and stylesheet engine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never heard of hook_for, so thanks for that. Your link pushed me in the right direction. I needed to use 'invoke'. It works like a charm now! :)

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know of `hook_for` before I did the research here. I knew that *somehow* this other generator was being invoked, I just didn't know *how*. Now I know, thanks to your question!